# Where is the "StubsBehaviors.DefaultValue" in Microsoft Fakes framework?

Tags: unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I am using the Microsoft Fakes framework to make some unit test stubs.

I tried to modify the stub behaviors with **StubsBehaviors.DefaultValue** according to the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#bkmk_changing_the_default_behavior_of_stubs).

But VS2012 keeps complaining it cannot resolve the **StubsBehaviors.DefaultValue**. And I searched a bit. No finding. This seems to be a enum or something. Which assembly is it defined in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is StubBehaviors and not StubsBehaviors. It is defined in *Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Stubs*

Comment: Thanks. Seems MSDN article has a typo.